# OpenGL ES 2.0: Shader Linking Fail

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I am trying to make a simple android program that uses openGL. So far, the shader linking fails and the Log info is,

**LOG**

```
Link info
    ---------
    OpenGL ES programs must have both a vertex and a fragment shader or a compute shader.
```

The shader compilation works fine. Here is the shader code:

**Vertex Shader**

```
attribute vec4 a_Position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = a_Position;
    gl_PointSize = 10.0;
}
```

**Fragment Shader**
precision mediump float;

```
uniform vec4 u_Color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = u_Color;
}
```

The steps that i am taking are,

```
final int programObjectId = glCreateProgram();

if(programObjectId == 0)
   return 0;

glAttachShader(programObjectId, vertexShaderId);
glAttachShader(programObjectId, fragmentShaderId);
glLinkProgram(programObjectId);
```

**Compilation Code**

```
public static int compileShader(int type, String code) {

    final int shaderObjectId = glCreateShader(type);

    glShaderSource(shaderObjectId, code);
    glCompileShader(shaderObjectId);
    int compilationStatus[] = new int[1];
    glGetShaderiv(shaderObjectId, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compilationStatus, 0);

    if(compilationStatus[0] == 0)
        glDeleteShader(shaderObjectId);
    return shaderObjectId & compilationStatus[0];
}
```

I am not sure how to solve this problem.

Comment: Where do you create the shaders / call glCreateShader? I would guess that either vertexShaderId is not of type GL_VERTEX_SHADER or fragmentShaderId is not of type GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER.

Comment: I pass in GL_VERTEX_SHADER or GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER based on the source.

Comment: Nevermind. Didn't think about the return values very clearly. Instead of returning the id of shader, i return some junk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the last line of `compileShader`: Here you perform a bitwise and operation on the shaderObjectId (an arbitrary number > 0) and compilationStatus (GL_TRUE or GL_FALSE). Since GL_TRUE = 1 and GL_FALSE = 0, the result of this operation can only be 0 or 1.

Lets just have a look at the GL_TRUE case, since with GL_FALSE the result will be 0 anyway.

```
For every even number x:
x & 1 == 1
For every odd number x:
x & 1 == 0
```

This means, if shaderObjectId = 3 (for example), the function will return 1.